Generalized Assignment Problem
I am seeking help to improve both my code and understanding of heuristics. I am new to heuristic algorithms and coding, but I really enjoy the subject. Do you have any suggestions for improving my skills in heuristic algorithms and coding?
Lastly, I would appreciate any feedback on the code below. The problem involves 5 agents, each with a specific capacity, and 25 jobs, each with an associated cost and resource consumption. Initially, I assigned the jobs to the agent that would result in the least resource consumption. Then, I started swapping assignments to decrease the total cost.
import numpy as np

# Function to calculate the total cost of a solution
def compute_cost(assignments, cost_matrix):
    total_cost = 0
    for agent, jobs in assignments.items():
        for job in jobs:
            total_cost += cost_matrix[agent][job]
    return total_cost

# Function to check if a solution is feasible based on resource constraints
def check_capacity(assignments, resource_matrix, capacities):
    remaining_capacities = capacities.copy()
    for agent, jobs in assignments.items():
        for job in jobs:
            remaining_capacities[agent] -= resource_matrix[agent][job]
            if remaining_capacities[agent] < 0:
                return False
    return True

def greedy_assignment_min_resource(cost_matrix, resource_matrix, capacities, max_iterations=1000):
    n_jobs = cost_matrix.shape[1]
    n_agents = cost_matrix.shape[0]
    
    # Initialize assignments and job tracking
    assignments = {i: [] for i in range(n_agents)}  # Initialize empty assignments for each agent
    remaining_capacities = capacities.copy()
    job_assigned = [False] * n_jobs  # Track if a job has been assigned
    
    # Iterating over each job to assign it to the agent with the lowest resource allocation
    for iteration in range(1, max_iterations + 1):
        print(f"Iteration {iteration}:")
        for job in range(n_jobs):
            if not job_assigned[job]:
                min_resource = float('inf')
                chosen_agent = None
                # Find the agent with the lowest resource allocation that has enough capacity
                for agent in range(n_agents):
                    resource = resource_matrix[agent][job]
                    if remaining_capacities[agent] >= resource:  # Check if agent has enough capacity
                        if resource < min_resource:
                            min_resource = resource
                            chosen_agent = agent
                # If we found a valid agent, assign the job
                if chosen_agent is not None:
                    assignments[chosen_agent].append(job)
                    remaining_capacities[chosen_agent] -= resource_matrix[chosen_agent][job]
                    job_assigned[job] = True
                else:
                    print(f"Job {job} could not be assigned due to resource constraints.")
                    return None, None
        
        # Check if all jobs are assigned
        if all(job_assigned) and all(len(assignments[agent]) > 0 for agent in range(n_agents)):
            break
        
        # Step 6: Print the current iteration's assignments and capacities
        print_assignments(assignments, remaining_capacities)

        if any(len(assignments[agent]) == 0 for agent in range(n_agents)):
            print("Infeasible solution: Not all agents have been assigned jobs.")
            return None, None
    
    # Calculate the total cost of this assignment
    total_cost = compute_cost(assignments, cost_matrix)
    return assignments, total_cost

# Generate the neighborhood structure by swapping jobs between agents
def get_neighbors(assignments, cost_matrix, resource_matrix, capacities):
    neighbors = []
    n_agents = len(assignments)
    
    # Iterate over all agent pairs
    for agent1 in range(n_agents):
        for agent2 in range(agent1 + 1, n_agents):
            # Iterate over all job pairs
            for job1 in assignments[agent1]:
                for job2 in assignments[agent2]:
                    # Create a deep copy of assignments
                    new_assignments = {key: value[:] for key, value in assignments.items()}
                    
                    # Swap jobs between agent1 and agent2
                    new_assignments[agent1].remove(job1)
                    new_assignments[agent2].remove(job2)
                    new_assignments[agent1].append(job2)
                    new_assignments[agent2].append(job1)
                    
                    # Check feasibility
                    if check_capacity(new_assignments, resource_matrix, capacities):
                        neighbors.append(new_assignments)
    return neighbors

# Local search function using neighborhood structure
def local_search_with_neighbors(cost_matrix, resource_matrix, capacities, initial_assignments):
    current_assignments = initial_assignments
    current_cost = compute_cost(current_assignments, cost_matrix)
    iteration = 0

    while True:
        iteration += 1
        print(f"\nIteration {iteration}:")
        
        # Get all neighbors
        neighbors = get_neighbors(current_assignments, cost_matrix, resource_matrix, capacities)
        
        # Evaluate each neighbor and find the best one
        best_neighbor = None
        best_neighbor_cost = current_cost
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            cost = compute_cost(neighbor, cost_matrix)
            if cost < best_neighbor_cost:
                best_neighbor = neighbor
                best_neighbor_cost = cost
        
        # If no improvement is found, stop the search
        if best_neighbor is None or best_neighbor_cost >= current_cost:
            print("No better neighbor found. Stopping local search.")
            break
        
        # Update current solution
        current_assignments = best_neighbor
        current_cost = best_neighbor_cost

        # Print current solution
        print_assignments(current_assignments, capacities)
        print(f"Current Total Cost: {current_cost}")
    
    return current_assignments, current_cost

# Helper function to print assignments and remaining capacities
def print_assignments(assignments, capacities,):
    for agent, jobs in assignments.items():
        print(f"Agent {agent + 1} -> Jobs {', '.join(map(str, jobs))}")

# Example usage
cost_matrix = np.array([
    [18, 19, 19, 17, 24, 25, 24, 25, 25, 23, 20, 21, 25, 17, 25, 21, 25, 19, 23, 19, 20, 15, 25, 23, 17],
    [25, 17, 18, 16, 18, 15, 23, 20, 19, 22, 23, 18, 17, 16, 16, 24, 16, 23, 23, 24, 19, 17, 15, 17, 17],
    [17, 25, 15, 23, 21, 20, 24, 17, 21, 22, 22, 15, 18, 23, 17, 22, 20, 24, 19, 18, 15, 15, 18, 19, 19],
    [21, 16, 25, 23, 18, 21, 18, 16, 21, 21, 15, 21, 24, 23, 24, 23, 20, 25, 24, 18, 19, 23, 22, 22, 16],
    [24, 16, 24, 19, 16, 25, 23, 25, 17, 21, 21, 22, 17, 25, 19, 21, 23, 19, 17, 24, 19, 15, 20, 15, 20],
])

resource_matrix = np.array([
    [25, 23, 5, 13, 6, 15, 24, 9, 17, 11, 5, 6, 8, 14, 9, 9, 21, 23, 13, 8, 22, 20, 24, 15, 20],
    [18, 8, 5, 20, 8, 7, 13, 17, 9, 16, 19, 11, 6, 12, 25, 23, 9, 21, 11, 15, 24, 23, 15, 21, 12],
    [7, 25, 13, 9, 16, 16, 8, 17, 5, 17, 10, 18, 21, 25, 17, 24, 20, 16, 9, 18, 18, 18, 16, 6, 24],
    [25, 11, 8, 7, 25, 20, 24, 16, 9, 15, 22, 10, 17, 6, 22, 11, 19, 20, 14, 14, 8, 18, 22, 18, 22],
    [7, 16, 20, 18, 13, 10, 15, 20, 5, 19, 11, 6, 11, 23, 15, 21, 15, 20, 21, 11, 9, 25, 17, 18, 12],
])

capacities = [58, 58, 62, 64, 60]

# Initial solution using greedy strategy
assignments, total_cost = greedy_assignment_min_resource(cost_matrix, resource_matrix, capacities)

# Apply local search with neighborhood structure
if assignments is not None:
    final_assignments, final_cost = local_search_with_neighbors(cost_matrix, resource_matrix, capacities, assignments)
    print("\nFinal Solution:")
    print_assignments(final_assignments, capacities)
    print(f"Final Total Cost: {final_cost}")
else:
    print("No feasible solution found.")
```


In essence, this is very similar to what we do in Timefold Solver: start with a Construction Heuristic (greedy assignment), then continue with a Local Search.
Here are some tips to improve your (meta)heuristic skills:

Scaling is more important than performance

Use bigger datasets, to detect scaling issues early on.
Use at least 3 datasets: x, 10x, 100x to see how size impacts KPIs.


Performance is also important

Measure the number of "moves per second".

In Local Search this is the number of moves you evaluate per second.
Without it, you're blind on the performance of the constraints and score calculation.
For comparison, we're at 10 000 moves per second for big datasets (5k assignments) with 50+ constraints on a cheap machine.


Incremental score calculation is the first of maybe 10 game changers for metaheuristics. On big datasets, it can increase your speed 100x easily.


The metaheuristics algorithms are 10% of the work, even with all the advanced tricks on top.

Anyone who tells you differently is working on academic code, not
production code.


Reproducibility is king.

Why? There Will Be Bugs. You want to find them, reproduce them, debug them and fix them all quickly. Without reproducibility, that's impossible.
To scale, you will need to use random selection. Seed your random.
Multithreaded solving (another one of those game changers) and reproducibility are NOT mutually exclusive.


Don't bias your move selections.

For example, in VRP if you want to select a visit and do that by selecting a vehicle and then a visit from that vehicle, then your move selection is biased towards visits in almost-empty vehicles.
It's almost impossible to detect from the outside and very hard to test from the inside, but it will hurt your results.


Benchmarking is your friend

